# Can't write legibly using a stylus on an Asus Transformer T100TA

Tags: windows-8.1, touchscreen

I recently bought an Asus Transformer T100TA to be used for note taking; mostly typing, but with the occasional drawing or bit of handwriting with the touch screen. Because the majority of my notes are typed, I didn't feel the need to get a tablet with a digitizer.

However, when I use a rubber tipped stylus with the T100TA, the lines appear broken, making handwritten notes impossible to read. I've tested a few different styluses, reinstalled drivers, and even used the same styluses on a floor model in store, and I still saw the same issues. I've been able to write fine on my old tablet, an Acer Iconia Tab W500 (with a Windows 8.1 x86 install), and on a Lenovo Miix 2 8, suggesting that there's an issue specific to the T100TA.

Would a fiber tipped stylus, or a stylus like the Jot Pro write better? Is there anything else I could do to improve it?

Answer (score 2):

The T100 lacks a high-end digitizer screen or Active Digitizer. It's a excellent value for what it brings to the table at the price point but if you got it for note taking with a stylus it's not going to work for you.